# Using an IDE to develop OpenSplice DDS applications

Tags: open-source, ide, data-distribution-service

I keep trying to configure Open Splice on the Eclipse platform but I'm not making any progress.  I use the Open Splice DDS in the Java Standalone mode. The Eclipse platform I work on is the Eclipse edition for Java EE developers (Helios).

The problem is: when I try to create a run configuration I need to select an application type from the left hand side menu. It seems that none of the available application types can be used to create a working run configuration for a batch file. I want to be able to start, stop, and open splice from inside Eclipse as well as to run the preprocessor and my applications without having to use a cmd console. I'm new to both Eclipse and OpenSplice and any help would be really important to me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does this link help: http://forums.opensplice.org/index.php?/topic/796-using-an-ide-to-develop-opensplice-dds-applications/

Comment: @paulsm4 Check out the question posed by Mike on that page, dated 24 August 2010... :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The problem is: when I try to create a run configuration I need to
>   select an application type from the left hand side menu. It seems that
>   none of the available application types can be used to create a
>   working run configuration for a batch file.

This explanation assumes you are in the Java perspective. Other perspectives will be very similar or the same.

Do not use the `Run Configurations` dialog box. In stead, select `Run` in the menu, which will show `External Tools` as its bottom item, which has a sub-item `External Tools Configurations...`. Clicking that will display a dialog box showing a list of possible configuration types on the left-hand side. Select the type `Program`, followed by clicking the `New Launch Configuration` icon on the top-left of your list. On the right-hand side, a number of edit boxes will appear allowing you to change the name of this launch configuration (which you can set to something like `ospl start`) set the launch command (like `ospl.bat` to be selected via `Browse...`), its arguments (like `start`) and several others like working directory and environment variables.

Click apply when done. From now on, the `ospl start` command can be run via the `Run` menu item, `External Tools` and then `ospl start`. Make this a favorite so it will be moved up in the menu to decrease the number of clicks.

The process can be repeated for any number of applications you want to start.

Answer (score 2):

If you are developing Java applications can now use OpenSplice Mobile which is a pure Java DDS implementation for j2se and Android.

OpenSplice Mobile comes with a mvn build system that can be easily used to create eclipse project (or simply imported into eclipse or IntelliJ).

You can find some examples at:

https://github.com/kydos/mobile-dds-demo

And get OpenSplice Mobile at:

http://www.prismtech.com/opensplice/software-downloads

A+